HID Device Call State Management Control Not Sending Reports
Trying to create an HID device that can detect whether a conference meeting on my pc has started or ended (Google Meet, Zoom, etc). Found a section in the HID documentation for Call State Management Control that seems to fit this well.
From my understanding, an output report can be received via a set report callback. An example that I got working was creating a HID keyboard device that can detect when CAPS LOCK is enabled. When I manually set CAPS LOCK in the PC's on-screen keyboard, my device receives the set report callback to note the state change.
When I try to look for the same set report callback using the documentation's Call State Management Control descriptor, no reports seem to be found. I tested this by starting and ending Zoom and Google Meet calls, and muting/unmuting my microphone.
Is the descriptor configured incorrectly? Am I missing any steps? Thanks in advance.
Call State Management Documentation:
https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/hutrr106-callstatemanagementcontrol_0.pdf
Sample descriptor:
0x05, 0x01, // UsagePage(Generic Desktop[1])
0x09, 0x13, // UsageId(Call State Management Control[19])
0xA1, 0x01, // Collection(Application)
0x85, 0x01, // ReportId(1)
0x09, 0xE1, // UsageId(Call Mute Toggle[225])
0x15, 0x00, // LogicalMinimum(0)
0x25, 0x01, // LogicalMaximum(1)
0x95, 0x01, // ReportCount(1)
0x75, 0x01, // ReportSize(1)
0x81, 0x06, // Input(Data, Variable, Relative, NoWrap, Linear, PreferredState)
0x75, 0x07, // ReportSize(7)
0x81, 0x03, // Input(Constant, Variable, Absolute)
0x09, 0xE0, // UsageId(Call Active LED[224])
0x75, 0x01, // ReportSize(1)
0x91, 0x22, // Output(Data, Variable, Absolute, NoWrap, Linear, NoPreferredState)
0x09, 0xE2, // UsageId(Call Mute LED[226])
0x91, 0x22, // Output(Data, Variable, Absolute, NoWrap, Linear, NoPreferredState)
0x75, 0x06, // ReportSize(6)
0x91, 0x03, // Output(Constant, Variable, Absolute)
0xC0, // EndCollection()


Tried to make my own descriptor with buffer bits to make up whole bytes. No change.
All testing done on Windows PC.

